# Restore permission and ownersip to root/home folders?

Tags: permissions, ntfs, chroot

I have migrated my system to a new hard disk and backed up my system to an external NTFS volume with **rsync- ahv**, a oversight and mistake given that NTFS volumes do not support UNIX permissions.

Normally I would back up to an ext4 volume however this disk has failed. So now I have a backed up system, which I have spent a lot of time tweaking, with all of it's permissions and ownerships blitzed, and logging into this system is possible (once I have restored it with rsync and reconfigured grub), but problematic to say the least.

I need to restore ownerships and permissions to the system. Is there a system of `chown`/`chmod` I can use to do this?

Comment: Have you access to a live CD/USB?

Comment: The next time, [back-up with tar](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR).

Comment: I don't mean to be the person pointing fingers and mistakes. Please don't interpret this as such but wouldn't dd have been a better option?

Comment: Bri - Yes. Whether I use a live CD, or a standalone install of Ubuntu however makes no difference to my problem, the files on the NTFS volume will still have lost their ownership, if not permissions.

Comment: iqnis - great advice and indeed I do use tar to archive files, as well as rsync which preserves the file structure for instant access should I need it. At the moment, I have 1 rsync backup, with incorrect ownerships.

Comment: K14JGT - No not for me, dd wastes resources as far as I'm concerned in this scenario. The rsync method is fast, doesn't use excessive memory, and works for me, until a drive fails and I make an oversight with regard to ntfs. I've often asked why the hell I need ntfs volumes. I'll probably keep asking this question.